# Errors related to CoreUI dependency Clink component vue

Tags: vuejs3

As soon as I build my project this error started coming and I am not able to resolve it
Details of the error I got,

```
Cannot destructure property 'to' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'to' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
    at getComputedTag (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./node_modules/@coreui/vue/src/components/link/CLink.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:47:27)
    at Proxy.render (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./node_modules/@coreui/vue/src/components/link/CLink.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:74:17)
    at renderComponentRoot (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:952:16)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814:46)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:217:19)
    at instance.update (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5927:51)
    at setupRenderEffect (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5935:5)
    at mountComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5725:5)
    at processComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5678:9)
    at patch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5166:11)
```